# WebStorm file completion for a specific directory

Tags: webstorm

I am working on a project where in different directories I have files called `index.js`.

My project structure starting from root is:

```
AllChannel/index.js
Search/index.js
```

Now I want to complete the path of `Search/index.js`. When I type initial letters of `index.js` then I get the completion popup with the above 2 suggestions and then I can  use down then Tab buttons to select the 
`Search/index.js`.

Let's say I had 100 directories with `index.js` files then I will have to press down arrow until I get to my desired result.

Is there a way in WebStorm to type `Se/inde` to get completion suggestion for `Search/index.js` path fast? Maybe there is mode when enabled WebStorm will literally look the entered chars in the realtive paths of files(i.e thinking realitve paths as strings).

I am attaching the screenshot[image]

Comment: Please show a screenshot of how that popup looks like and where in the code you are trying to complete it.

Comment: @LazyOne I updated the question with the screenshot.